# Can't get data from table columns on web page using selenium web driver in java

Tags: java, selenium

I want to get some continuous data from table columns on web pages using selenium web driver in java.
I am getting the following error:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to bind to locking port
>   7054 within 45000 ms
>       System info: os.name: 'Windows 8', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.2',java.version: '1.7.0_75'
>       Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver

I have tried by updating selenium and firefox.

```
     import java.io.File;

     import org.openqa.selenium.By;
     import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
     import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
     import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
     import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

    public class webcrawler {


    public static String substringBetween(String str, String open, String close) {
                if (str == null || open == null || close == null) {
                    return null;
                }
                int start = str.indexOf(open);
                if (start != -1) {
                    int end = str.indexOf(close, start + open.length());
                    if (end != -1) {
                        return str.substring(start + open.length(), end);
                    }
                }
                return null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            System.getProperties().put("http.proxyHost", "192.168.10.9");
            System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPort", "8080");
            String volume = substringBetween("Ticket 3098,OrderID 9712,TRD0890084 Buy 1 Contract(s) of CRUDE10-JY15 @ 59.57","Buy","Contract(s)");
                System.out.println("----->"+volume+"<-----");

                //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Aami\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe"); 
                //ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); 
                //options.addArguments("--test-type"); 
                WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();

                //WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

                driver.get("http://only-testing-blog.blogspot.in/");
                Thread.sleep(5000);

                //Get number of rows In table.
                 int Row_count = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='post-body-6522850981930750493']/div[1]/table/tbody/tr")).size();
                 System.out.println("Number Of Rows = "+Row_count);

                 //Get number of columns In table.
                 int Col_count = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='post-body-6522850981930750493']/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td")).size();
                 System.out.println("Number Of Columns = "+Col_count);

                 //divided xpath In three parts to pass Row_count and Col_count values.
                 String first_part = "//*[@id='post-body-6522850981930750493']/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[";
                 String second_part = "]/td[";
                 String third_part = "]";

                 //Used for loop for number of rows.
                 for (int i=1; i<=Row_count; i++){
                  //Used for loop for number of columns.
                  for(int j=1; j<=Col_count; j++){
                   //Prepared final xpath of specific cell as per values of i and j.
                   String final_xpath = first_part+i+second_part+j+third_part;
                   //Will retrieve value from located cell and print It.
                   String Table_data = driver.findElement(By.xpath(final_xpath)).getText();
                   System.out.print(Table_data +"  ");   

                   driver.quit();
                  }
                   System.out.println("");
                   System.out.println("");  
                 } 

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have a zombie process of the driver running in the background?

Comment: no, i do not know about that

Comment: Well, when you start a service on your computer, it binds to a port (exposed by the network adapter) identified by a number between 1 and 65535. The exception you're getting indicates that binding the driver's service to the given port has failed, which may mean that a different service has already bound itself to that port on your computer. Check your services, and close whichever one is sitting on that port.

Comment: oh, i got it, so now what to do?

Comment: Easiest way? Restart your computer and try again. Caveat: This won't work if the process that is sitting on port 7054 is initiated on system startup.

Comment: Please change the question title to be something more specific and related to your actual question.